Internal server error: Failed to resolve import
Сomponents are not loaded. I don’t understand why. Maybe I didn't connect something somewhere?
<template>
  <MainLayout></MainLayout>
</template>

<script setup>
import MainLayout from "../layouts/MainLayout.vue"
</script>

nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  pages: true,
  modules: ['nuxt-icon', '@pinia/nuxt', '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['pinia-plugin-persistedstate'],
  },
  css: ['~/assets/css/style.css'],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  }
})

package.json
"dependencies": {
  "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
  "nuxt": "^3.11.2",
  "pinia": "^2.1.7",
  "tw-elements": "^2.0.0",
  "vue": "^3.4.27",
  "vue-router": "^4.3.2"
},



What is the first snippet code in (which file)? You overall do not need to import a file from the layouts directory because it is automatically done for you. Otherwise, the Nuxt config and package.json are quite unrelated.

This is not how it is supposed to work.
Please create a ~/layouts/default.vue file and write this in it
<template>
  <div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

and have this in your app.vue
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

Then you'll be able to have a layout wrapping a page properly.

The benefit of using default.vue is the fact that you do not need to set anything else for it to work. Because otherwise you will need to tell what's the name of the layout you want to use like this
<script setup lang="ts">
definePageMeta({
  layout: 'main-layout'
})
</script>

Give a read to this page for all the details.
